# How can I show the week numbers in the calendar shown at the top in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, calendar

I would like to display the week numbers in the calendar that is shown in Ubuntu with GNOME shell v3.26 when clicking on the date in bar at the top of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you have **dconf Editor**, launch it and navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/calendar/show-weekdate`. Then disable *Use default value* and set *Custom value* to **True**.

Alternatively just open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.calendar show-weekdate true
```

Comment: That simple! I like the gsettings method, except that I would not have figured this out without googling. But that is addressed by the other answer. Still much better than under windows where, somewhere around 2017, had to install a different calendar tool to see week numbers. +1

Answer (score 45):

Edit: since early 2018 GNOME Tweak tool was renamed to GNOME Tweaks - [source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/-/blob/98b20195571c76c29feaba4a58cf416d37a7ecc9/NEWS#L8-9).

You can do that with the GNOME Tweaks.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Open the application after installing it.

1. Go to the "Top Bar" menu item from left.

[image: Ubuntu Tweak Tool]

2. There's an option called "Show week numbers". Check it.

[image: Calendar with week numbers]

Comment: Still working here in 2022 under Pop. Thank you.

Comment: Great tool, much more intuitive than gsettings! +1