# Is it possible to change the start date for the week numbers in the Gnome 3 top bar calendar?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, calendar

In Ubuntu 18.04, I see in gnome-tweak-tool I have the option (under Top Bar) to show week numbers in the calendar that appears when I click on the time in the top bar.

My employer (a university) uses numbered weeks but they don't start in January. It varies, but week 1 is usually the week that contains the 1st August (e.g. in 2018/19 week 1 started on 30th July 2018).

It would be useful to have the week numbers displayed in the calendar, but only if I could change the start date so the numbers shown align to those used by my employer. Is it possible to configure the year start date for week numbers?

Comment: Would https://askubuntu.com/questions/962177/how-can-i-show-the-week-numbers-in-the-calendar-shown-at-the-top-in-gnome-shell?rq=1 be helpful?

Comment: @DKBose Thanks, but the answers to that question explain how to display the week numbers, including a method using gnome-tweak-tool as I say in my question. My question is about how to change the numbering of the weeks, rather than how to display them (which I know how to do).