# calendar weeks not visible

Tags: calendar

I would like to see the calendar week if I click on the date.

[image]

The solution of this answer does not work [gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.calendar show-weekdate true](https://askubuntu.com/a/962200/42348)

Comment: But in your link posted there, the second answer is correct for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Terrance quite rightly states in his comment, in 20.04.1 I can confirm that the second answer in your posted link works.

[image]

[image]

The week number is displayed alongside any date you care to choose within the calendar.

Comment: Why is it not editable by default - without installing a fancy config-tool?

Comment: @guettli if this answers your question, please consider accepting it to enable others to easily find it. Thank you.